# Animated file explorer for windows xp

Tags: windows-explorer, animation

Is there any tool to view windows[xp] file explorer with animation?

Comment: What is it that you wish to be "animated" ?

Comment: slide in slide out animation on opening/closing  the folder..

Comment: Please go back and see if more of your questions have answers that you can mark as accepted.

Comment: @Dennis thanks for the reminder.. I have marked few which seemed to answer the query...

Comment: This is really a specific request. Check out "WindowsFX" from Stardock. Maybe that will do. (It's not what you EXACTLY looking for but maybe it's close enough.) Oh and you need Windows 7 to use it.